# Proving that the restriction of a homomorphic function is also a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, proof-writing, group-homomorphism

> Suppose $f$ is a homomorphism from $A \to B$, and $C \subset A$. Further suppose that $r$ is a function that maps $C \to B$ $|$ $r(C) = f(C)$

and since I wish to prove that $r$ is also a homomorphism I would show that:

> since $r$ behaves like $f$ but is simply restricted to the subgroup of $A$ (called $C$), and $f$ is a homomorphism by definition, if there exists $x,y\in C$ such that $f(x, y) = f(x) f(y)$ then it's also true that $r(x, y) = r(x) r(y)$ for some $x,y\in C$, thus showing that $r$ is a homomorphism

and if this is true, then it is additionally true that if we limit ker$(f)$ to the scope of the subset $r(K) ∀k\in K$, then ker$(r)$ = ker$(f) \cap k$

please let me know what your thoughts are on this problem and correct me where you see fit; all help and input is appreciated

Comment: Can you work with the definition of a homomorphism?

Comment: @EricAuld yes sir! how would you propose incorporating that into the proof?

Comment: If you want to prove that $r$ is a homomorphism, list the defining properties of a homomorphism, and see if you can show that $r$ satisfies them. (Since you know $f$ does.)

Comment: @EricAuld thank you! would my edits reflect using the definition of homomorphism correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If $r:=f_{|C}$, then $r(c_1c_2)=f(c_1c_2)=f(c_1)f(c_2)=r(c_1)r(c_2)$, and $r$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker}(r) &= \{c\in C\mid r(c)=e_B\} \\
&= \{c\in C\mid f(c)=e_B\} \\
&= \{c\in A\mid f(c)=e_B \wedge c\in C\} \\
&= \{c\in A\mid f(c)=e_B\}\cap \{c\in A\mid c\in C\} \\
&= \operatorname{ker}(f)\cap C \\
\end{alignat}